# Username on spring security randomly not set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, yaml

I have a spring boot application, that is using spring security / basic authentication for developing an api interface.

The application has no DB so I set an encoder for the password that is stored in the application.yml file, encoded, in a property.

Sometimes, when I startup the application with mvn spring-boot:run, the application is not reading the username property from the yml file and sometimes instead gets data correctly.

It's strange, because I just rerun the application and the property is not working.

Someone has an idea of this?

Here it is the yml file:

```
security:
   username: myuser
   password: xxxxxxx-the-encoded-password
   strenght: 8
```

Here it is the Spring @Configuration file :

```
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private Integer passwordStrenght;
  @Value("${security.strenght:8}")
  public void setPasswordStrenght(Integer passwordStrenght) {
    this.passwordStrenght = passwordStrenght;
  }

  private String username;
  @Value("${security.username}")
  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  private String password;
  @Value("${security.password}")
  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser(
        User.builder()
          .username(username)
          .password(password)
          .authorities("USER")
      );
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(passwordStrenght);
  }

  @Autowired
  private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

  @Bean
  public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
    return new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(
          "/", 
          "/dashboard"  // will stores web pages
      ).permitAll() 
      .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .httpBasic()
      .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
      .and().cors()
      .and()
      .exceptionHandling()
      .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);

    http.addFilterAfter(new SecurityFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
}
```

**strong text**

```
    2018-07-27 19:19:34.833  WARN 10809 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: username cannot be null
2018-07-27 19:19:34.862 ERROR 10809 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: username cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:379) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at com.my.app.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: username cannot be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User$UserBuilder.username(User.java:377) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.my.app.config.SecurityConfig.configureGlobal(SecurityConfig.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Thanks, Davide.

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace to share with us to see what specific error; issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced simmilar problem. Solved by using propeties class.
You can inject @ConfgiruationProperties class here. then you get userName && password from properties.

```
@Scope(value = "singleton")
@ConfigurationProperties("com.custom")
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Data
public class AppProperties {

private String userName;
private String password;
}
```

then yml:

```
com:
  custom:
    userName: 
    password:
```

@autowired AppProperties :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
AppProperties appProperties;
}
```